# Can I have multiple servers if I only have one publicly facing IP?If so, how is this done?

Tags: web-services, networking, dns

I have 5 servers, some of which are serving the same network service (i.e. http), but I want them to appear on the public network as separate machines. www1.mydomain.com, www2.mydomain.com

I can move the internal port numbers to another port, but how would I map the DNS name to these other machines?

Comment: Why do you want the machines to appear on the public network as separate machines?  This is not normally done because it exposes your internal site configuration to the external world.

Comment: I have multiple servers for different courses. Dept website web design course websites, DB course server, etc. So some of the normally open ports (i.e> 80) will need to expose more than one server. I was hoping to do this with different domain names. It's cleaner, hides the internals and (if later I get more IPs) easier to move to another IP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a content switch, or an layer 4 through layer 7 switch.  A content switch takes incoming packets and routes them to the appropriate server based on criteria you specify.  Using a content switch, you can take Web traffic that is bound for one IP and spread it out over multiple IPs.

For Web requests, you can switch based on the HTTP 'Host' header.  The 'Host' header specifies from which host the client desires to get the resource from.

I know that Citrix* has a free version of their Netscaler software that includes a content switch.  If you want a completely free switch there is HA Proxy: http://www.haproxy.org/

- Disclaimer - I work for them.

Comment: Thanks!! I'll certainly look into that. At least now I nave A solution, I can work from there to find the RIGHT solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot solve this with DNS. If you have only one IP address, all HTTP traffic will go to port 80 (or 443) on that address. If you want to split those requests by which HTTP host is being requested, you need something that can look at the HTTP Host header field and forward the request appropriately.

Comment: So you think it can only be done at the server? I tend to agree, but what specifically I do to make this real?